# How to localize text which has format "[-][+]Xh Xmin"

Tags: c++, c++11, time, localization

I receive time in seconds and I need to provide compound text which has format "[+][-]Xh Xmin", where X is number from range 01-59. The problem is that system has multiple locales (I have access to current locale) which means "h" and "min" abbreviations must be adjusted according to current system language.

First solution which comes to mind is to perform translation by hand and hard-code all possible abbreviations. Then use map to lookup for a translation. But of course this is error-prone and time-consuming and overall not an elegant solution. 
I think possible solution would involve usage of something similar to `std::get_time()` or any other locale-dependent time-related function from standard library or boost.

Expected result for provided time value 10 hours and 25 minutes would be:
using locale en_GB "+10h 25min"
using locale ru_RU "+10ч 25мин"
using locale ja_JP - I don't even know, must perform research and learn some rules (this is also why to translate by-hand is undesirable solution)